# what is curve data which is used in dcmmkcrv of dcmtk library

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

Currently i am using dcmtk for pac and modality console communication . In dcmtk one execute file is there **dcmmkcrv**. It is used for store the curve data in dcm file.

Now my question is ,

what is **curve data** ? I need some example for that curve data.

Comment: You could for example look for electrocardiography curve data. Also look in the docs for [dcmmkcrv](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmmkcrv.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description for Curve Data can be found in a deprecated DICOM Standart of 2004.

The standart is available here: http://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2004/04_03PU3.PDF

Page 681 - C.10.2.1.4 Curve data

Note that after 2004 Curve data is not defined within the DICOM standart anymore.